How to setup iptables filtering on a network interface with a subnet based on per-application isolation using cgroups v2 in Linux?
I have been trying to setup a per-application filtering on a network interface using cgroups v2 but I can't.
Here is an example using network namespaces and veth pairs:
ip netns add somenetns
ip link add foo type veth peer name bar netns somenetns
ip link set foo up
ip -4 addr add 10.0.0.1/24 dev foo
ip -6 addr add fd00::1/64 dev foo
ip netns exec somenetns ip link set bar up
ip netns exec somenetns ip -4 addr add 10.0.0.2/24 dev bar
ip netns exec somenetns ip -6 addr add fd00::2/64 dev bar
ip netns exec somenetns ip -4 route add default via 10.0.0.1 dev bar
ip netns exec somenetns ip -6 route add default via fd00::1 dev bar
ip netns exec somenetns ip link set lo up

What I want is to make only applications running inside certain cgroup to have their listening points available to the subnet of network interface (in the case of network namespace, have 10.0.0.1 available inside network namespace).
I ran a basic TCP server listening on IP of network interface:
# sudo bash -c "echo \$\$ >> /sys/fs/cgroup/blah/cgroup.procs; nc -k -l 10.0.0.1 1234"

# sudo ip netns exec nsx nc -z 10.0.0.1 1234
Connection to 10.0.0.1 1234 port [tcp/*] succeeded!

Connection is made.
But when I try to apply some iptables rules, it fails:
iptables -A INPUT -i foo -m cgroup --path blah -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -i foo -j DROP
iptables -A OUTPUT -o foo -m cgroup --path blah -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -o foo -j DROP

# time sudo ip netns exec nsx nc -z 10.0.0.1 1234
^C
real    0m37.504s
user    0m0.000s
sys 0m0.003s

Is there a way to make a listening point in the IP of a network interface available to its subnet being the program which is listening, is inside a cgroup and filter all the rest?
If it is possible to do that, what would be the correct iptables rules that I must apply?
